# How to unit test a function that executes SQL without affecting the db in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I am struggling to unittest a function that doesn't return anything and executes delete operation. The function is as follows:

```
    def removeReportParseData(self, report_id, conn=None):
        table_id = dbFind(
            "select table_id from table_table where report_id=%s", (report_id), conn
        )
        for t in table_id:
            self.removeTableParseData(int(t["table_id"]), conn)
            dbUpdate("delete from table_table where table_id=%s", t["table_id"], conn)
```

I want to make sure that the commands were executed but don't want to affect the actual db. My current code is:

```
    def test_remove_report_parse_data(self):
        with patch("com.pdfgather.GlobalHelper.dbFind") as mocked_find:
            mocked_find.return_value = [123, 232, 431]
            mocked_find.assert_called_once()
```

Thank you in advance for any support.

Comment: Are you sure that this is what you want to do? 

A typical testing approach would be to create a database environment for your unit tests that has the same schema as the rest of your application, in which you can CRUD records to your heart's content during the execution of your test suite without having to worry about it impacting the state of your other database(s).

Comment: I got what you mean and that makes a lot of sense but for now, I want to move with the approach that I stated above (even though it may not be as great as the one you proposed).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to execute SQL without executing it, so to speak, however if you are on MySQL you might be able to get fairly close to what you want by wrapping your queries in `START TRANSACTION;` and `ROLLBACK;`

i.e. you might replace your queries with:

```
START TRANSACTION;
YOUR QUERY HERE;
ROLLBACK
```

This will prove that your function works without actually changing the contents of the database.

However, if it is sufficient to simply test that these functions would execute ANY query, you could alternatively opt to test them with empty queries, and simply assert that your dbFind and dbUpdate methods were called as many times as you would expect.

Again, though, as I alluded to in my comment, I would strongly suggest NOT having your test suite interact with even your development database.

While there is certainly some configuration involved in setting up another database for your tests, you should be able to find some boilerplate code to do this quite easily as it is very common practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. " ... simply assert that your dbFind and dbUpdate methods were called as many times as you would expect."
 This is what I am actually trying to do but can't find a way as I am quite new to Python unittest.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do you have the code for what your test looks like so far? You should be able to do this with https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html and the call_count property.

Comment: I have tried several ways with Mock but it didn't work. I am adding my current code in the post itself.